# How to achieve Sliding window in android like we have in google hangouts

Tags: android

I am trying to add the sliding window feature in my Android application,
    can any one help me out in achieving this.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Link] <https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B70-_23F047iM2licDZiblZoOUk/edit?usp=sharing>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.slide_view);
```

Whole tutorial you can find here: http://bladesofandroid.blogspot.com/2013/06/hi-guys-in-this-post-i-will-be-showing.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is the NavigationDrawer http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html